# Resources for using TFS for Agile Project Development?

Tags: project-management, version-control, team-foundation-server

Our company just installed TFS for us to start using for project development processes and source control.  They want us to start using it to manage our projects as well.  We have a small team, no current bug or task tracking software, and 2 developers of the 3 have experience with any actual methodologies.

What books, websites, and/or other information can you recommend for us to use to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2010" is a good book, covers pretty much all of TFS's capabilites. I'd also recommend reading the blogs of the various ["ALM Rangers"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudioalmrangers/understanding-the-visual-studio-alm-rangers).  They have a silly name but they do offer good advice.

There are a lot of other TFS blogs on MSDN, I won't list them all, but a good place to start would be the blogs of Brian Harry, Buck Hodges, Bill Heys and Jim Lamb. If you go to [Buck Hodges's](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/) blog and look on the right hand side you'll see "Blog - Link List"

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled a list of links on Agile that I am working on for a presentation:

https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!threadID=G_eN74brLH3k%2FBDRGfDQoQzMDkttUl

It has links to presentations, books etc. on Agile and Scrum, both for TFS and Software Development in general.

Answer (score 0):

[Professional Team Foundation Server 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470943327) by Wrox is new book on TFS2010. It Provides a broad overview of Team Foundation Server for developers, project managers, testers and everyone wanting to use TFS.